# Hard drive write operation expected rates

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

It is known that SSDs are suboptimal for "high-write" environments.  What common business and/or personal computing use cases are "high-write" situations, which are "low-write" situations, and what are the relative frequencies of these situations (e.g. "of all the hard drives in all the world, half of all bits are written to X times in Y days, but a quarter of all bits are.... etc etc).

I realize that this information may vary wildly depending on all manner of things.  If your data is limited to a particular use case that is fine, please share.

The more concrete and thorough the numbers the better.  Citations, please, if applicable.

Comment: Simply buy the right SSD for your workload. You determine your workload by either measuring or estimating. This older answer of mine links to a number of relevant resources https://serverfault.com/q/641726/37681

Comment: I do not know, a priori, what our workload will be as we will be "renting out" these machines.  My question revolves around "typical usage" patterns.  e.g. how many bits were read from disk the world round yesterday, how many bits were written around the world yesterday, what is the ratio of those two numbers?  Other measures might be useful.